# Unix - show some characters in file by line number

Tags: unix, sed, file-processing

I have a very huge file and need to look at a few characters in the middle of some huge line.

Is there a way to show easily characters from `n1` position to `n2` position in line number `l` in some file?

I think there should be some way to do it with `sed`, just cannot find corresponding option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You better use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==line_number {print substr($0,start_position,num_of_characters_to_show)}' file
```

For example, print 5 characters starting from the 2nd character in the line 2:

```
$ cat a
1234567890
abcdefghij
$ awk 'NR==2 {print substr($0,2,5)}' a
bcdef
```

If you really need to use `sed`, you can use something like:

```
$ sed -rn '2{s/^.{1}(.{5}).*$/\1/;p}' a
bcdef
```

This matches `2-1=1` digits after the beginning of the line and then catches `5` to print them back. And all of this is done just in the line `2`, so we use `-n` to prevent the default print of the line.

Answer (score 3):

The elegance of UNIX has always lain in its ability to string together relatively simple programs into pipelines to achieve complexity. You can do a `sed`-only solution but it's not likely to be as readable as a pipeline.

To that end, you can use a combination of `sed` to get a specific line and `cut` to get character positions on that line:

```
pax> echo '12345
...> abcde
...> fghij' | sed -n 2p | cut -c2-4
bcd
```

If you just want to use a *single* tool, `awk` can do it:

```
pax> echo '12345
...> abcde
...> fghij' | awk 'NR==2{print substr($0,2,3);exit}'
bcd
```

So can Perl:

```
pax> echo '12345
...> abcde
...> fghij' | perl -ne 'if($.==2){print substr($_,1,3); exit}'
```

In both those cases, it exits after the relevant line to avoid processing the rest of the file.

Comment: You will probably also need to pipe to `tail` to get the exact line number. For example, to get the 25th line you need `head -n 25  | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 0):

One solution using only [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), that insert newlines characters just before and after the substring and uses them as flags to remove all content not between them, like:

```
sed -n '2 { s/.\{5\}/&\n/; s/.\{2\}/&\n/; s/[^\n]*\n//; s/\n.*//; p; q }' infile
```

Assuming `infile` like:

```
1234567890
abcdefghij
```

It yields:

```
cde
```

Not that range is from `2` to `5` but start counting from zero and it excludes the end (so characters 2, 3 and 4). You can handle with it or do some arithmetic just before the command.